# How to sort an array of formcontrols in angular Reactive form

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

```
I have a list of form controls in a reactive form angular


this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  
 firstName: [''],

  lastName: [''],

  stage: [''])}
```

I have a radio button on top of form to Sort the fields alphabetically.
How to achieve this functionality.

Any help is appreciated.[image]

Comment: As far as I know, sorting html elements has nothing to do with the form configuration. How are you displaying the fields in the template?

Comment: Using angular material                                                                                               <form [formGroup]="newForm" class="form-container">                                                                                        
 <mat-label>FirstName </mat-label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <mat-form-field class="full-width">
              <input matInput id="firstName" formControlName="firstName"  required>
            </mat-form-field>

Comment: Seems like you'd be better of using @akkonrad 's answer. If you wanted to do this programmatically, you'd need to store your form definitions in an interface, populate an array with your form definitions and iterate over them in the template using `*ngFor`.

Comment: The advantage is that you can programmatically sort that array, but for 3 form fields this seems unnessecary.

Comment: I have 10+ fields actually, for a demo purpose have shown only three. @MikeS. Can you please elaborate/show an example. I am new to angular. Will be helpful if you can

Comment: I whipped up something for you [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wulnir?file=src/app/app.component.ts). It's not specific to your case (it doesn't use angular-material), but the general approach would be similiar.

Comment: Thanks Mike. It helped a lot. But the corresponding text boxes were not getting sorted..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244790/discussion-between-ps-dev-and-mike-s).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in your template, based on the radio input value:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="sorAlphabetically; else defaultSort">
   <!--- input A --->
   ...

   <!--- input B --->
   ...

   <!--- input C --->
   ...
</ng-container>

<ng-template #defaultSort>
   <!--- input B --->
   ...
   
   <!--- input A --->
   ...
 
   <!--- input C --->
   ...
</ng-template>
```